# Applet getting Hang

Tags: java, applet, multithreading, deadlock

I found following post [Java 6 JVM Hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370710/java-6-jvm-hang) with somewhat similar exception that am getting. There is no deadlock. But many threads are in WAIT state. Stack trace is as follows. My Client JRE is 1.6.0_18.

```
"Applet 1 LiveConnect Worker Thread" prio=4 tid=0x03382800 nid=0xe40 in Object.wait() [0x03acf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x27f2b400> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x27f2b400> (a java.lang.Object)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Browser Side Object Cleanup Thread" prio=6 tid=0x03369800 nid=0x13b0 in Object.wait() [0x03a7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x27f2b488> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x27f2b488> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$BrowserSideObjectCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
"Threaded tile loader thread #0" prio=4 tid=0x03437000 nid=0x3f8 in Object.wait() [0x04a6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x284c4d10> (a ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader$TaskThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x284c4d10> (a ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Threaded tile loader thread #0" prio=4 tid=0x04398400 nid=0x163c in Object.wait() [0x04a1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x28489400> (a ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader$TaskThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x28489400> (a ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x03d14400 nid=0x154c in Object.wait() [0x0416f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x27f30210> (a java.awt.EventQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x27f30210> (a java.awt.EventQueue)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Comment: 1st step - identify the code that might be causing this and give it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have threads waiting on instances of `ilog.views.tiling.IlvThreadedTileLoader`, so there should be some other threads doing `notify`. Hard to say more without seeing code.